# Is protobuf.net v2 ready for production usage?

Tags: .net, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, production-environment

Quick Query Here, we are using .net 3.5. We want to change our BinaryFromatter serialization to Protobuf Serialization for obvious performance gains...

Is Protobuf v2 ready for deployment with production code ?
Latest in wiki is protobuf-net r668 ...  Is using this ok ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I've been using v2 solely for many years now (on sites like this one). I can't think of any good reasons not to use that version.